# Jav save the date and time at a particular syncpoint and restart from same point

Tags: java

My application looks for daily updates from API. So I wanted to save the date and time at particular point  and then restart(let's say tomorrow) from the same sync point to look for updates.

Something like this structure:

```
main()
{
long sync = getlastSavedStateTime()

lookForUpdates()

saveStateTimeAgain()
}
```

Comment: Write to file after each each sync. Read from file for next sync.

Comment: what java function should i use to save date and time to a file? I cannot write every object to the file.

Comment: You need to serialize java object and write it to disk. It may or may not be easy depending on the application structure. If you find yourself needing to do this, then I think you have design problem. Read more http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html .

Comment: This helped. Thanks!!